# JavaFX 11 javafx.embed.swing does not exist

Tags: java, javafx, intellij-idea, gradle

Есть проект на OpenJDK11 + OpenJFX11. Запускал через Maven, но необходимо перейти на Gradle. Делал всё по их [туториалу (Modular IntelliJ with Gradle)](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx)

module-info.java

```
module Application {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javafx.graphics;
    requires javafx.media;
    requires java.desktop;

    opens ru.app to javafx.fxml;
    exports ru.app;
}
```

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.7'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

javafx {
    modules = ['javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml', 'javafx.graphics', 'javafx.media']
}

mainClassName = "$moduleName/ru.app.Main"

task jlink(type: Exec) {...}
```

При запуске:

```
> Task :compileJava FAILED 
 /home/.../Class.java:3: error: package javafx.embed.swing does not exist
 import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
                    ^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Я попробовал добавить `requires javafx.embed.swing` в module-info, но `модуль не найден` (`javafx.embed` тоже самое)

Как мне добавить этот модуль и запустить проект?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне удалось запустить проект. Решением было:

1. Добавить библиотекой [JavaFX jmods](https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/). File -> Project Structure -> Libraries -> выбрать папку с распакованными jmod'ами
2. Добавить в `build.gradle` в modules `javafx {modules = ['javafx.swing']}`
3. Добавить в module-info.java `requires javafx.swing;`

Comment: а что именно там надо скачать jmod или JDK? на сайте JavaFX

Comment: @Arsen нужно скачать именно jmod